# Probability of 3 specific items chosen as a sample?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, combinations

If there are 3 students who all goes to different schools, with each school population being 300, 500, and 700, respectively. If the school wants to select a 10% sample from each school, what is the probability that these 3 students end up in the sample?

10% from each school means 30 students selected from the first school, 50 from the second, and 70 from the third.

Would that be choosing 1 specific student from 300, 500, and 700, and then the rest of the students from 299, 499, and 699 students over the total number of combinations:

(300C1 * 500C1 * 700C1)*(299C29 * 499C49 * 699C69) / (300C30 * 500C50 * 700C70)

Comment: There is only *one* choice  for selecting one *particular* student from each school. if you replace your first three terms by $1$, you will get the answer, though there are simpler ways to arrive at it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:  A simpler approach has already been posted, essentially $\frac{30}{300}\frac{60}{600}\frac{90}{900}$

Comment: @trueblueanil I realized that after simplifying the corrected version of doudoudreams' expression.  Essentially, there are $30$ spots the particular student from the school with $300$ students could occupy and so forth.

Comment: @trueblueanil sorry do you mean that (299C29 * 499C49 * 699C69) / (300C30 * 500C50 * 700C70) will simplify to 30*60*90/300*600*900 ?

Comment: Oh, by mistake in the comment I took the  schools to have $300, 600 and 900$ Your combinatorial formula will simplify to 30∗50∗70/(300∗500∗700) Don't forget the parentheses for the denominator ! –

Comment: Also, to understand the logic better, it is better to write the expression as $\frac{30}{300}\cdot\frac{50}{500}\cdot\frac{70}{700}$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this question is from a book or class, this is a trick question, that should probably not have been presented to you at this time.  The book should have first trained you better.

The key fact is the probability, that applies to each student.

There are $3$ events, $E_1, E_2, E_3$, that each represent the event that one of the pertinent students is chosen.

You are being asked to compute the probability that all $3$ events happen simultaneously.

You are given that $p(E_1) = p(E_2) = p(E_3) = 0.1$.  That is, the probability of each of the events occurring is $(0.1)$.

These are *independent* events, meaning that the probability of one of the events occurring is *unaffected* by whether one of the other events occurs.

Therefore, the probability that all $3$ events occur is

$$p(E_1) \times p(E_2) \times p(E_3) = (0.1)^3 = (0.001).$$